# Has anyone created a more CQS-compliant facade over the ASP.NET MembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

The `System.Web.Security.(Sql)MembershipProvider` class has some really bad design flaws:

There are many command methods which return values (AND throw exceptions), e.g.:

`bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword);`

There is the ability to retrieve a user's password which one should never, ever do:

`public abstract string GetPassword(string username, string answer);`

And there is a serious shortcoming of not being able to generate alphanumeric-only password without subclassing.  (Sorry, can't find a link.)

Has anyone created a more CQS-compliant, better-designed facade over the default ASP.NET MembershipProvider?  If not, does MSFT have plans to improve this *ahem* somewhat less than ideal implementation?

Comment: For the record, if the answer is no I'm willing to hop on GitHub and give it a shot.

Comment: I don't want to start a(nother) long discussion about the proper way to implement exceptions, but just because a method returns a value that doesn't mean it shouldn't also throw exceptions. My preference is to only throw exceptions in _truly exceptional_ circumstances (meaning they cannot be recovered from) which realistically could occur regardless of whether the method returns a value or not.

Comment: CQS is pretty firmly established as good programming practice.  If you want to handle an exception, handle it.  But if I say "update this user's password to this value", a failure is exceptional in my mind.